# MPI_Irecv type cast required error

Tags: c, parallel-processing, compiler-errors, mpi, pgi

My code can be found on my github:
https://github.com/chrismunley/ParallelProgramming/tree/master

The error I get is:
PGC-W-0095-Type cast required for this conversion (my_laplace.c: 112)
PGC-W-0095-Type cast required for this conversion (my_laplace.c: 120)
PGC/x86-64 Linux 17.5-0: compilation completed with warnings

Anyone know what I am doing wrong with the Irecv? I think it has to do with the parameters. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do not just post a link to your whole code and an error message. Read [ask] and [mcve]. Demonstrate your attempts to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a compiler warning indicating that it's needed to implicitly cast a data type to another that is potentially unsafe.  In this case, it appears that you're passing in a reference to a MPI_Status variable to MPI_Irecv, where MPI_Irecv is expecting a reference to a MPI_Request variable.

Comment: Awesome thank you, can't believe I missed that. I looked at the parameters so many times. You're a god.